# Delete Order associated Invoice, Shipments, Creditmemos

Tags: magento2.2.2

```
public function execute()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    echo "=========================<br/>";
    $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
    $order_id = $request->getParam('order_id');

    $registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
    //Delete Order value passed from url - baseurl/ebayorder/index/delete/order_id/145
    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($order_id);
    if(!empty($order)){       
        $registry->register('isSecureArea','true');
        $order->delete();
        $registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
        echo "Order Deleted...</br>";
    }
    echo "================</br>";
}
```

Above code will delete the order.

**Next, want to add delete Invoice, Shipments, Creditmemos that is associated to that order.**

Thank You!

**Solution**

```
    public function execute()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    echo "=========================<br/>";
    $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
    $order_id = $request->getParam('order_id');

    $registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
    //Delete Order value passed from url - baseurl/ebayorder/index/delete/order_id/145
    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($order_id);
    if(!empty($order)){
        $registry->register('isSecureArea','true');
        $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
        if($invoices){
            foreach ($invoices as $invoice){      
                $invoice->delete();
            }
        }
        $creditnotes = $order->getCreditmemosCollection();
        if($creditnotes){
            foreach ($creditnotes as $creditnote){ 
                $creditnote->delete();
            }
        }            
        $shipments = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
        if($shipments){
            foreach ($shipments as $shipment){      
                //Delete shipment
                $shipment->delete();
            }
        }

        //Delete Order
        $order->delete();
        $registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
        echo "Deleted...</br>";
    }
    echo "================</br>";
}
```

Comment: Post your solution as answer

Comment: what is the issue here ?